# Building dynamic angular forms with ngrepeat and ngform

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I'm using AngularJS 1,5 and the trick which I'm looking for is below.

For example, this is form:

```
<form name="main">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-init="subForm='tags'+$index">
      <ng-form name="{{subform}}"
        <input type="text"  name="username" ng-model="user.username" required/>
        <input type="text"  name="name" ng-model="user.name" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
        <input type="hidden" name="status" ng-model="user.status"/>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to watch my models gathered from the ng-form child in the controller to check on their validity.

```
 self.Scope.$watch('main[subForm].$valid', function () 
 {
      if (self.Scope.myform.subForm.$valid)
      {
           $scope.user.status = true;
      }
});
```

Is there any way to implement something like that or should I create a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

> In this sample we create our model as **"forms"** and send it to the directive, the **parent form** is valid if one of that forms is complete, by complete each form the **user state** will change

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form name="parent_form">
        <ng-form data-form="parent_form" data-list="forms"></ng-form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="parent_form.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
       $scope.forms = [
          { name: "form1", isValid: false },
          { name: "form2", isValid: false }
       ];
    });
```

**ngForm.html**

```
 <div name="form_{{form.name}}" ng-repeat="form in list">
            <h3>{{form.name}}</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="form.user.username" ng-required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="form.user.name" ng-required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" ng-model="form.user.email" ng-required="true" />
            </div>
            <label>user state is:</label>{{form.user.status}}
            <hr />
        </div>
```

**ngForm.js**

> Directive with form handler

```
app.directive("ngForm", function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "ngForm.html",
        scope: {
            list: "=",
            form: "="
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            var isValid = function (list) {
                var hasUser = $filter("filter")(list, { hasUser: true }, true);
                if (hasUser.length >= 1) {
                    scope.form.$invalid = false;
                } else {
                    scope.form.$invalid = true;
                }

                angular.forEach(list, function (item) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(item.user)) {
                        if ((angular.isDefined(item.user.username) && item.user.username !== null) &&
                        (angular.isDefined(item.user.name) && item.user.name !== null) &&
                        (angular.isDefined(item.user.email) && item.user.email !== null)) {
                            item.user.status = true;
                            item.isValid = true;
                            item.hasUser = true;
                        } else {
                            item.user.status = false;
                            item.isValid = false;
                            item.hasUser = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            scope.$watch("list", function (nVal) {
                if (nVal) {
                    isValid(nVal);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want those forms inside a parent form in order to send them with a submit button otherwise those data will be useless a side from other functionalities that touch all forms.Thus,the parent form remain necessary

Comment: if one of that forms (in parent form) is invalid, we can submit the parent form?

Comment: yes, I can send while there is at least one model is valid

Comment: @AhmedChebbi, i change the answer and hope helps you, comment me if something wrong in it.